# Android Java : what's wrong with indexOf?

Tags: java, android, substring, indexof

I don't understand what's wrong with the IndexOf function ???

```
public String[] PseudoExisteTest() {
  // looking if an XML tag contain "OK"
String exampleText = "<result>OK</result>";

int ind1;
int ind2;

String returnTable[] = new String[4];
String tag="result";
String textresult;

ind1=exampleText.indexOf("<"+tag+">");   // 0
ind2=exampleText.indexOf("</"+tag+">");  // 10

textresult=exampleText.substring(ind1+tag.length()+2, ind2);

    if ((textresult=="OK")) {     // YES  => Normally we pass here (="OK") !  
        returnTable[0]="It'OK";
        }
    else {
        returnTable[0]="Not, value is : "+textresult+"!";  // Not, value is : OK !!! ????? 
    }
    returnTable[1]="blabla";

    return returnTable;
}
```

The value is "OK" but on the condition, that's don't works well ????
Is anybody can help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the textresult?

Comment: Replace `textresult=="OK"` with `textresult.equals("OK")`. This is how you check equality for strings.

Comment: Refer to BackSlash's comment. He is correct.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. 
I am a beginner and it is indeed a rookie mistake;-) 
Again thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `==` to do a comparison of Java Strings. For objects in Java, which includes Strings, `==` tests whether the *objects* are the same. Instead, say `textresult.equals("OK")` or `textresult.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")`.

As the comments say, see also [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)